# Explain "Coloring the Mandelbrot Set in Matlab" line 13

Tags: matlab, math, fractals, mandelbrot

## Preface on the Former Post

I had a question related to this post from 4 years ago ["Coloring the Mandelbrot Set in Matlab"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844510/coloring-the-mandelbrot-set-in-matlab/20844717#20844717) but I don't have enough reputation to comment directly on the post.

The code [Chris Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546084/chris-taylor) provided in the post was this

```
function mandelbrot(n, niter)

x0 = -2;   x1 = 1;
y0 = -1.5; y1 = 1.5;
[x,y] = meshgrid(linspace(x0, x1, n), linspace(y0, y1, n));

c = x + 1i * y;
z = zeros(size(c));
k = zeros(size(c));

for ii = 1:niter
  z   = z.^2 + c;
  k(abs(z) > 2 & k == 0) = niter - ii;
end

figure,
imagesc(k),
colormap hot
axis square
```

## The Questions

I had two to be exact:

1. What is the matrix k for?
2. What does the line `k(abs(z) > 2 & k == 0) = niter - ii;` actually mean?

---

## Sidenotes Not Particularly Vital to the Questions

Two more quick things, first being if there is any other way to ask a question about a specific post, please let me know. I would comment on the answer itself but I don't have enough reputation to do that and I also didn't want to submit an "answer" that wasn't really an answer on that person's post. 
The second matter, is there any way I could just ask the author of the answer (Chris Taylor) directly what that part of his code means? If not is there a way I can tag them in this so that they can see this?

Thank you!

Comment: i think due to the complex mathematical nature of calculating a mandelbrot-set this question might be better off in mathematics

Comment: `k` is the matrix that stores the color indices for the indexed color image of the fractal. The statement basically reads "All unset colors (`k == 0`) whose complex magnitude is greater than 2 (`abs(z) > 2`) are now set to the color at index `niter - ii`"

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, thank you @PatrickRoberts! I'd love to accept this as the answer but you'd have to post it as such, if you could